# Progression with variable in exponent

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponential-sum

what is the solution of this kind of progressions:

$1 + \delta^{T} + \delta^{2T} + \delta^{3T} + \dots $

I have tried hard and look through the website but still I don't know hot to solve the issue of the $T$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is a geometric series.  $\delta^{nT}=(\delta^T)^n$.

Comment: Do you mean that I can write it as the sum from 0 to infinity of $(\delta^{T})^{n}$ ?

Comment: Yes.  That is the geometric series that you need to consider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$1 + \delta^T + \delta^{2T} + \cdots = (\delta^T)^0 + (\delta^T)^1 + (\delta^T)^2 + \cdots = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (\delta^T)^k = \frac{1}{1 - \delta^T}$$

(Sum of a geometric series)